# Protect Development Wordpress site using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

How can I password protect development Wordpress site complete from search engines and humans using htaccess.

Also can you specify in which folder I need to keep .htaccess file in wordpress to complete block it.

I tried it with following htacess file but after logging in only homepage showsup and other pages don't work.

```
SetEnvIf Host dev.test.com passreq
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/user/dev.test.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any
```

What am I doing wrong? Currently I am keeping .htaccess file in *wp-content/theme/theme_name/.htaccess*

Answer (score 0):

You should put your file in your Webroot to completely password protect it. Putting it under *wp-content/theme/theme_name will only protected files served from this directory